# Problems Running ImageMagick Conditional Padding From ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, imagemagick

I am working with a ColdFusion web app that takes an uploaded image and resizes it 4 times using ImageMagick. I am trying to add to apply some some conditional formatting to it and the code works via Command Prompt but it doesn't work correctly via the CF app.

Here's the code that is being sent to the server from CF (and works fine in the command prompt):

```
C:\path\cmd.exe /S /C ""C:\path\ImageMagick\magick.exe" "C:\path\800x77.jpg" -resize 600x600 -strip -quality 85 -gravity center -background white -extent "%[fx:w^<250?250:w]x%[fx:h^<250?250:h]" "C:\path\result600x250.jpg""
```

The carets are there to escape the lesser than signs but appear to break the ImageMagick formatting, as IM returns an image that is cropped to 250x250, rather than 600x250. Any ideas on how I can make it work correctly when CF runs it?

ImageMagick 7, CF2016, Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter

**EDIT:**
The code doesn't use a cfexecute. I added double quotes to the code being appended to the shell code and that gets me closer. Here's the line generating that part of the code for the shell script:

```
<cfset local.shellArguments &= ' -gravity center -background white -extent ""%[fx:w\^<#arguments.argResizeMinWidth#?#arguments.argResizeMinWidth#:w]x%[fx:h\^<#arguments.argResizeMinHeight#?#arguments.argResizeMinHeight#:h]""'>
```

Comment: What does your CFExecute tag look like with this information? Are you using double quotes everywhere?

Comment: @JamesMoberg Actually, the problems I am having are related to other logic, which I think I can fix. If you submit the double quotes as the answer, I will mark it correct.

Comment: "The code doesn't use a cfexecute"  What does it use to run ImageMagick?

Comment: @Ageax It's an old script that uses Java (I think). The app has some pretty old pieces to it!

Comment: Ah!  Since CF runs over java, it's probably what cfexecute uses beneath the covers anyway.